# Spring 5.3.9 MVC XML Configuration: ViewResolver Not Mapping To Controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xml-configuration

I am beginning to learn the Spring Framework and am currently learning Spring MVC. I am using Spring version 5.3, and I am having issues with loading the JSP files in the views directory. I understand from the notes that they removed suffix pattern matching, but I have no idea what my XML configuration should be to match this new change.

Can someone please help me get this issue sorted, and show me what the XML configuration should be for Spring 5.3 MVC. It's halted my progress for three whole days!

Note: I am aware that Spring Boot is the norm these days but I want to learn Spring from scratch even if it is more tedious to work with.

Additional Note: I am using entirely XML configuration for this.

I am not using a build tool at the moment as I will learn one later on. I build my projects from the command line:

cd into webapp folder --> jar -cvf mvc-test.war * --> run on Tomcat 9 server

JDK: 11

IDE: VS Code

My Controller Class:

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "test-page";
    }
}
```

My web.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

My spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My project structure is below (Sorry I don't know how to format this):

Root Projet Folder: mvc-test

mvc-test: src and webapp folders

src: main/java/com/controller/HomeController.java

webapp: WEB-INF

WEB-INF: lib, views, spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml, web.xml

views: test-page.jsp

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ32f.png)

Comment: Can you share a picture of your expanded project, that would be very helpful

Comment: You could use `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver` instead of `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`. Then the call would be xxx/test-page. Also I believe your `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to be faulty

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The `InternalResourceViewResolver` is  a dedicated/specialized extension of the `UrlBasedViewResolver` changing to that won't solve a thing. The mapping is perfectly fine as you want to map everything.

Comment: What goes wrong? Why do you think it doesn't match? As long as there is a `test-page.jsp` inside `/WEB-INF/views/` it will match. I suspect the problem is your creating of a war file. You apparently only include what is inside `webapp` (and I suspect you are either using Maven or Gradle). Instead of doing `jar -cvf ....` use your build tool to generate the war file. You are now going to miss libraries, compiled classes etc. etc.

Comment: Hi zawarudo! I added a pic of my project structure in VS Code (The lib folder just has all the Spring framework JARS)

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, you're correct I am currently not using a build tool at the moment I am compiling from the command line using jar -cvf project.war * command. Not sure why this would be an issue though. Are you saying I should execute the command within the root project dirctory rather than just the webapp?